# Aceitar respostas

Tags: debate, perguntas, resposta-aceita

Fiz uma pergunta, na qual obtive duas respostas **diferentes** porém a minha solução exigiu a utilização dessas duas respostas. Basicamente ambas são essenciais na solução do meu problema.
Minha dúvida é: para quem eu marco como "resposta aceita"?

Comment: Se nenhuma das duas realmente resolve o problema por conta própria, talvez o melhor seja postar sua solução completa (com os devidos créditos). Votar nas respostas também é uma boa ideia. Em termos de reputação, os autores das respostas deixam de ganhar pouco, e o site fica com uma resposta completa como solução para outras pessoas que se depararem com o problema.

Comment: Penso da mesma forma @Molx, outros usuários podem ter duvidas parecidas, e alguma das 3 pode sanar ou ajuda-los.

Comment: Concordo com os colegas. E ainda reforço que a menção às respostas que te ajudaram deve eventualmente cobrir a "perda" de reputação pela não aceitação de uma delas, por meio dos votos que elas devem receber por quem ler a sua nova resposta-completa.

Answer (score 9):

Tendo em conta um utilizador futuro que encontre a pergunta porque tem o mesmo problema seria simpático ter uma resposta que explique e resolva o problema. Nesse caso é boa ideia uma resposta que unifique as ideias que as outras respostas referiram.

Se ambas deram contributo igual e o problema não fica resolvido com apenas uma delas acho que colocar uma nova resposta é boa ideia.

Se achares que essa nova resposta não tem contrubuto teu, ou seja é inteiramente fruto do contributo das outras respostas podes, para além de referir as fontes, marcar a resposta como *wiki*.

<sub>**PS:** se colocares o link para a pergunta podemos também premiar as respostas existentes com votos, uma vez que foram úteis para o problema</sub>