# Sou a favor de "divisão de resposta" (marcar mais de uma como resolvida)

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Acredito que nós iniciantes, aprendemos demais aqui no SOpt, e há casos que existe mais de 1 resposta muito esclarecedora e bem feita, que fica muito difícil marcar 1 só.

Para mim, até para criar um critério de qual escolher, já nem tem como! Principalmente pela minha imparcialidade.

Como fazer nesse caso?

Me ajudem!

Comment: Marque a que ache melhor e vote nas outras. A classificação das respostas não é feita só pela aceitação, é também feita pelo número de votos. Normalmente o número de votos até é o melhor indicador de qualidade.

Comment: Votar sim, sempre... O problema de marcar a "aceita" é que ela fica em destaque, querendo ou não... Sei que o aceita é somente +15, mas dá destaque especial... parece injusto... 

Comment: Dê uma recompensa se você acha que a outra resposta merece reputação adicional.

Comment: Mas aí dá na mesma! Vou "beneficiar" mais um que o outro... (apesar que a maioria dos casos não faz muita diferença) rs

Comment: Está a pôr as coisas nos termos errados. Não se trata de beneficiar um ou outro autor da resposta, trata-se de qualificar as respostas.

Comment: você está dizendo que as respostas são como cheetos, é impossível comer um só?

Comment: @ramaral Mas foi o único "critério" que pensei... as 2 são boas, 50% 50%, vou ter que tirar "cara ou coroa" rs

Comment: @Blogueira Por aí! rs Impossível!

Comment: Tem sempre a possibilidade de não aceitar nenhuma.

Comment: Relacionada: [Marcar resposta correta por consenso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4089/91)

Comment: Relacionado [Aceitar respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4183/2541).

Comment: Lembrando que se uma completa a outra, é possível sempre que um dos autores de uma resposta edite a sua e construa uma resposta completa, incorporando a outra, atribuindo devidamente os créditos. Se é benéfico para a comunidade, deve ser feito.

Comment: As respostas não podem ser iguais. Normalmente você vai na prática ir por um dos caminhos propostos. Aceite a que vai usar na vida real. Se usou um pouco de cada, aí é um caso mais raro, tente imaginar se só tivesse sido postada uma, e depois se só tivesse sido postada a outra, qual seria o cenário mais útil. Se nada resolver, entre no http://random.org que lá resolve

Answer (score 11):

Isto já foi discutido antes na rede, e de fato não faz sentido ter mais de uma aceita, até porque não somos um fórum. É preciso ter uma resposta que respondeu melhor, uma que se destacou, uma que responde todas as partes da forma que deseja. Se não é completa, que seja a mais completa.

Atendeu tudo o que queria? É essa. Respondeu melhor? Escolha essa. Tem uma outra que tem um bom complemento, ou que responde algum outro ponto que não era o que esperava? Provavelmente não é essa. Tem outra mais engraçada? Não é essa. Tem que ser a responde melhor segundo o seu critério. Ainda está difícil? Então talvez seja culpa da pergunta ter dado margem para respostas boas que precisam ser escolhidas juntas para ser justo com o conhecimento.

Ser justo com o usuário não é critério. Pode votar em ambas. E pode colocar recompensa para premiar a outra (ou quem sabe as duas). Mas aceitação é sobre o conhecimento passado. Tem que decidir qual das duas ou mais respostas é a que merece mais ser a que recebe o verdinho, nem que seja por um tiquinho. Seria confuso ter mais que uma aceita.

Peça para os candidatos fazerem algo na resposta para ajudar você decidir :P

Eu só evitaria a sorte. É até um exercício legal escolher uma. A vida é assim, o trabalho em TI é assim. Escolha errado e carregue o problema pro resto da vida :D :D :D Sem pressão! :D

Se está em uma situação assim, sorte sua e de todos.

Comment: Eu falei brincando o cara e coroa! rs... E estou pensando agora como "É até um exercício legal escolher uma." ... Posso usar como algo a mais para "rever" cada detalhe das respostas, e até as vezes coisas que deixamos passar e só vemos quando revisamos!

Comment: «Escolha errado e carregue o problema pro resto da vida» ahahahah

Answer (score 3):

Mas ambas são boas no seu entendimento ou ambas são boas que resolvem de maneiras diferentes, mas ambas eficientes?

Porque ao meu ver duas respostas responderem a mesma coisa ai é critério seu pessoal ao escolher, pode escolher a mais antiga, ou a que lhe agrada mais, se ambas lhe agradarem igualmente, você pode escolher uma como correta e a outra você pode oferecer uma recompensa.

Mas vou ser bem sincero contigo, as vezes pensamos que duas respostas são boas, mas ambas sendo diferentes é provavel que uma mesmo que funcione ainda sim seja uma resposta ruim, um exemplo foi uma pergunta que vi sobre [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) ontem, tinha duas respostas supostamente "boas", mas ai apareceu uma terceira que mostrou falhas nas outras duas respostas, mas até antes da terceira aparecer as outras duas respostas para muita gente pareceram correta, até ganharam upvotes.

Foi necessário uma pessoa com maior conhecimento técnico para explicar que tinha problemas ali nas outras respostas, ou seja não adianta você achar que uma resposta é boa porque funciona, ou porque a pessoa copiou um artigo qualquer, ou porque o cara vem afirmar um texto com uma meia duzia de palavras bonitas, você tem que fazer a analise técnica, tem que ver se realmente ambas respostas são funcionais, ou são os "caminhos corretos".

O que eu mais vejo no site são respostas apreçadas de uma turminha do barulho que se preocupa em dar suporte técnico e ganhar score, mas não tem conhecimento técnico real ou mais profundo e nem se preocupam com isso e o pior, tem gente que dá upvote nesse tipo de resposta sem avaliar e tem autor que aceita a primeira resposta só porque funciona.

Então a minha resposta para este caso, para você e para todos frequentadores da comunidades é:

**Avaliem antes votar ou escolher uma resposta**

Comment: As 2 são excelentes e praticamente iguais (pelo fato de ser uma pergunta simples). 

Comment: @rbz mas a pergunta que te faço, isso é uma avaliação pessoal sua? você tem conhecimento técnico aprofundado no assunto para ter certeza se ambas são excelentes de verdade? Entendeu? Esse é o propósito da minha resposta.

Comment: Então, é assim... a pergunta é simples, eu já tinha minhas ideias do que poderia ser. Pelas respostas tive certeza e mais informação quanto a isso. E creio que seja impossível algo a mais que aquilo. Não é um daqueles assuntos que perguntamos N e ela vira N1,N2,N3 depois N1.1,N1.2,N1.3,N2.1,N2.2,N2.3,N3.1,N3.2,N3.3 entendeu? rs Mas eu fiz a releitura e achei um detalhe bacana que vou usar como critério! Depois de muita pressão! hahah

Comment: @rbz eu vou repetir mais uma vez, vc pode achar que este é o caminho ideal, o autor da resposta também pode achar e ainda sim não ser, faça o seguinte, poste o link aqui.

Comment: @rbz prometo que vou ler com calma, sei que ambos colabores são muito bons, ainda sim sempre pode haver uma resposta como melhor, de qualquer forma a minha primeira dica **ainda é:** *você pode escolher uma como correta e a outra você pode oferecer uma recompensa para agradecer.*

Comment: Vixe eu ficaria sem pontos se fizer isso sempre, porque nessas questões mais simples sempre tem resposta muito boa, entende!? rs

Comment: @rbz acho que o ponto é avaliar com calma uma a uma, vou te contar um segredo, eu tenha umas 5 perguntas no site, duas com "otimas" respostas, mas que não domino bem o assunto, por falta de tempo ainda não testei ou estudei a fundo, por isso não optei por nenhuma das respostas, claro que eu já deveria ter analisado, mas como não tive tempo então optei por me manter *"agnóstico"*

Comment: Então... eu costumo deixar lá, até uma vez acabei esquecendo, mas quanto menos acumular melhor... Mas você entendeu bem sobre a pergunta ser simples e acredito que "não tenha" mais o que complementar né!? Pra piorar, só se mais alguém adicionar mais 1 resposta no mesmo nível! kkkkkkk

Comment: @rbz eu pessoalmente acho raro (raríssimo mesmo) quando há duas respostas que completam todos os pontos, mesmo que ambas sejam boas, é provavel que uma das duas esteja melhor ou com algum detalhe "IMPAR" que faz toda a diferença. Eu prometo que vou ler com calma ambas e te dizer o que vejo tecnicamente que pode ser o diferencial em ambas.

Comment: Opa! Valeu professor! 

Comment: O caso da pergunta de *string* em  C# tá uma bagunça, choveu negativo pra todo lado, o que pra mim tem parte de retaliação. Eu postei na minha resposta que as outras têm problemas, acharam que mereciam negativo. A minha tem negativos, pode ser que tenha problemas, mas ninguém falou nada. Então o que eu penso? :)

Comment: @Maniero era deste caso mesmo que estava me referindo, antes da sua resposta parecia para muitos que as outras respostas estavam 100%, mas você fez os apontamentos técnicos que mostravam problemas, ainda sim é um caso que mostra que as pessoas continuam a dar upvote nas postagens com problemas, o que eu gostaria muito que as pessoas começassem a avaliar tecnicamente e não só dar up pq parece estar certo, ou dar up pq funcionou em um caso especifico, mas não chegou nem a testar de fato. Eu acho a sua atitude de dar contra respostas algo que salva a comunidade muitas vezes, eu tento fazer também

Comment: Infelizmente nem sempre é possivel convencer a comunidade que as outras postagens tem problemas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mas eu acho que os ups e downs ali, pelo menos a maioria foram de sacanagem. Inclusive uma das pessoas que deram down na minha e up nas outras teve uma forte discordância comigo há pouco tempo e deu pra ver que pegou birra. Inclusive inicialmente eu não tinha negativado as outras, mas com downs que eu levei sem saber porque não deu mais pra segurar. Vou ver se faço uma mudança pra colocar mais testes

Comment: @Maniero eu acredito, acabei só pegando o caso como exemplo, na verdade o exemplo é antes da sua resposta ter aparecido, quero dizer, ambas respostas lá pareciam boas, mas na verdade continham problemas. O que é bem comum de ocorrer no site, os down e ups vieram depois, só queria pegar um caso recente que ainda esta fresco na memoria dos outros.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi, mas o que queria dizer, é que virou zona :) O certo ali era nem ter respostas, porque sequer sabemos se ´o que o AP deseja.